# Converting numbers to text from mysql in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

In my MYSQL database I have many headers to columns that are in this format- `2345X32X12.......` `2345=survey id, 32=page id, 12= question id.`..

Under each header contains the question of that specific ID set. With PHP I am trying to grab the text of each question of each ID set to place in a csv file.

Right now when I open my csv file from my web server, I get that format as the headers `(2345X32X12)` in the columns of an excel file;

I want to get the question under each column to look like this - What is your age?.........I hope this makes sense

In another table in my database the numbered headers define the question-in A1: 2345X32X12 B1: What is your age?

**Code:**

```
<?php
// connection with the database 
//$sid =$_SESSION['sid'];
//echo $sid;
$id=$_GET['sid']; 
echo $id;

$dbhost= ""; //your MySQL Server 
$dbuser = ""; //your MySQL User Name 
$dbpass = ""; //your MySQL Password 
$dbname = "y";    
$link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db($dbname); 
$tablename = "survey_".$id; // this is the tablename that you want to export to csv from mysql. 
$sql = "Select * from $tablename"; 
//create  code for connecting to mysql 
$Connect = @mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) 
or die("Couldn't connect to MySQL:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno()); 
//select database 
$Db = @mysql_select_db($dbname, $Connect) 
or die("Couldn't select database:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno()); 
//execute query 
$result = @mysql_query($sql,$Connect) 
or die("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno()); 


exportMysqlToCsv($tablename);
function exportMysqlToCsv($tablename,$filename = 'Results.csv'){
    $sql_query = "select * from $tablename where id=2";
    // Gets the data from the database

    $result = mysql_query($sql_query);

    $f = fopen('php://temp', 'wt');
    $first = true;

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        if ($first) {

            fputcsv($f, array_keys($row));

            $first = false;
 }
  fputcsv($f, $row);

    } // end while

    $size = ftell($f);
    rewind($f);
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Content-Length: $size");

 // Output to browser with appropriate mime type, you choose ;)
    header("Content-type: text/x-csv");
    header("Content-type: text/csv");
    header("Content-type: application/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");

    fpassthru($f);

    exit;
}

?>
```

Comment: I think you are saying that you want the column names in your export to be something other than the column names in the database is that correct?  If so where would the name you desire come from?

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't very clear. You first say that the issue is these funny column names, but then you say you're trying to get the question into the csv file. I don't see what one has to do with the other.

Anyway, for a column with a heading like that, use:

```
$ids = explode('X', $heading);
```

You can then loop over `$ids` getting the numbers like 2345, 32, and 12. Without knowing more about the structure of your database, it's hard to know precisely where this should go in your code or what you want to do with them.

Comment: Please post the schema for your table and some sample rows.

Comment: In one table (table_answers) it reads A1:2345X32X12 A2: 2345X32X13 A3:2345X32X14.......Under these columns are the answers to those questions...In another table (table_questions) those questions are defined. For Instance it reads- A1:2345X32X12/B1:What is your age?..............................next row A2:2345X32X13/B2:What is your gender?

Comment: I need some sort of join statement within my PHP to add the actual questions as headers instead of their ID's...